# KSoap2 Send complex XML

Tags: java, android, object, soap, ksoap2

I working on a Android application using Eclipse w/ Android Developer Tools ( Build: v21.0.0-531062 )

I am trying to send a soap message with and XML structure like such

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header/>
<v:Body>
    <n0:GetContent id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="http://11Giraffes.com/">
        <SerialNum i:type="d:string">aac3691e</SerialNum>
        <ID i:type="d:string">7fc2cf3f8445ca8e3383ea870f3ae2ce</ID>
                    <SysInfo>
                          <IIP i:type="d:string">127.0.0.1</IIP>
                          <CPU i:type="d:string">15%</CPU>
                    <SysInfo>
    </n0:GetContent>
</v:Body>
```

But I can not get the data that should be under SysInfo to nest. It all goes into the "GetContent" namespace.  I have tried to use the various ksoap2 jar files to get SoapObject.adddSoapObject() but none of them pull up that method as defined.

What I actually get:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header/>
<v:Body>
    <n0:GetContent id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="http://11Giraffes.com/">
        <SerialNum i:type="d:string">aac3691e</SerialNum>
        <ID i:type="d:string">7fc2cf3f8445ca8e3383ea870f3ae2ce</ID>
        <IIP i:type="d:string">127.0.0.1</IIP>
        <CPU i:type="d:string">15%</CPU>
    </n0:GetContent>
</v:Body>
```

Jars Tried:

- ksoap2-android-2.5.2.jar
- ksoap2-android-2.5.5.jar
- ksoap2-android-2.6.5.jar
- ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar
- ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar

The documentation states that any jar past 2.5.5 would contain the method "addSoapObject()" but it does not.

[ksoap documentation link](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks) in the section "Adding an array of complex objects to the request"

Any help in getting this correct would be appreciated.

Comment: I have it.  Eclipse took a while to show / accept the method in the UI. I am using the 
jar ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar and I can now call "addSoapObject()"  Lets see if I get the results that I am looking for.